# replaceWith & fadeIn/fadeOut - hover not working afterwards

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a task here that requires heavy DOM manipulation. Because this can have a bad impact on the performance, I clone the element, make the changes there and replace the clone with the original.

After replacement, the elements have a hover function.

Because I want faded transition, I do the change like this:

```
myElement.fadeOut(500, function(){
    myClone.hide();
    myElement.replaceWith(myClone);
    myClone.fadeIn(500);
 });
```

This is working, but after that the hover functionality does not work anymore. When I remove the callback from `fadeOut`, I can hover again but the timed transitions does not look good anymore.

*What can I do about it? Why do the elements lose their hover-functionality when using the callback?*

Comment: where var declaration for myClone? what is myClone? href? id? class?

Comment: Can we see the hover part of the code also? I sounds like something with `.live()`: http://api.jquery.com/live/ might be the solution.

Comment: The `.clone()` function doesn't, by default, copy over event handlers and data attached to the element.

Comment: @Steeven Never `.live()`. Use `.on()` for jQuery 1.7+ otherwise use `.delegate()`.

Comment: @Steeven They perform the same functionality, provided you convert from `.live()` to `.delegate()` or `.on()` correctly, but the newer methods are implemented in a much better way. The `.live()` function has also been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7, which means in future versions of jQuery it could potentially be removed entirely. Take a look at the [jQuery docs for `.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have a different solution for you. CSS approach:

You can set one of your element's position;

```
#myElement { top:100px; left:200px; }
#myElement, #myClone { position:absolute; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var myElement = $('#myElement');
var myClone = $('#myClone');

var myEleTop = parseInt(myElement.css('top'));
var myEleLeft = parseInt(myElement.css('left'));

myClone.hide();
myClone.css({'top':myEleTop+'px','left':myEleLeft+'px'});//sets position here

myElement.mouseenter(function() {
    myElement.fadeOut(500, function(){
      myClone.fadeIn(500);
    }
});
myElement.mouseleave(function() {
    myClone.fadeOut(500, function(){
      myElement.fadeIn(500);
    }
});

});
```

or you can just use [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) and [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) methods, i am not really experienced with these methods but try this:

```
myElement.mouseenter(function() {
    myElement.fadeOut(500, function(){
      myElement.remove();
      myClone.appendTo($('.container'));
      myClone.fadeIn(500);
    }
});
myElement.mouseleave(function() {
    myClone.fadeOut(500, function(){
      myClone.remove();
      myElement.appendTo($('.container'));
      myElement.fadeIn(500);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats really nice, again ;-) Thanks!

Comment: glad i can help :) loved your questions btw, they all includes my interests ((:

Comment: sorry for interfering with your solution, but I have the same problem with a cloned element and I'm not able to handle the mouseenter/mouseleave correctly. Please have a look at my question for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11768145/problems-with-my-attempt-to-bypass-jscrollpanel-overflow-auto

Answer (score 1):

When an object is cloned, the clone will no longer have event listeners attached to it. One way to fix it is to attach the event handlers using "on":

```
$("my-clone-container").on("hover", "my-clone-selector", myHoverHandler);
```

This way, whenever you add a clone, it will automagically handle hover events as you want it to. See the [docs for 'on'](http://api.jquery.com/on/).